# Failed to find byte code for java/util/function/BiConsumer

Tags: android, kotlin

This problem happened on API 23.I think this is lambda conversion problem.
I wrote listener functions like this:

```
fun read(child: String, onSuccess: (datas: List<RestaurantModel>) -> Unit, onFailure: (errMsg: String) -> Unit) {}
```

It's working great on API 27.I don't wanna write interface for this pattern.This lambdas more clean for me.Does anybody know the solution?

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to find byte code for java/util/function/BiConsumer
at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
... 32 more
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to find byte code for java/util/function/BiConsumer
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunTransform.doTransform(InstantRunTransform.java:312)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunTransform.transform(InstantRunTransform.java:178)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to find byte code for java/util/function/BiConsumer
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:146)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunTransform.doTransform(InstantRunTransform.java:307)
... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to find byte code for java/util/function/BiConsumer
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1431)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to find byte code for java/util/function/BiConsumer
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.AsmUtils.lambda$static$0(AsmUtils.java:89)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.AsmUtils.loadClass(AsmUtils.java:307)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.AsmUtils.readInterfaceHierarchy(AsmUtils.java:216)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.AsmUtils.readInterfaces(AsmUtils.java:251)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.AsmUtils.loadClass(AsmUtils.java:288)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.IncrementalVisitor.instrumentClass(IncrementalVisitor.java:342)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunTransform.transformToClasses2Format(InstantRunTransform.java:406)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunTransform.lambda$doTransform$3(InstantRunTransform.java:268)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunTransform.lambda$null$4(InstantRunTransform.java:297)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
```

Comment: Post your `build.gradle`

Comment: @ice1000 Which gradle do you want brother?App or Project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.It's gradle bug.I downgraded gradle version to 3.0.0.It's compiling now.

- This bug is fixed in last version.You don't need downgrade.Just update your gradle version to last.

Answer (score 0):

BiConsumer is part of the Java 8 Platform and was introduce to Android in API 24. ([reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/function/BiConsumer))

When building your project to Java 8, kotlin lambda's are converted to [Java 8 functional interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html)

In your `build.gradle` app. Try compiling your project with Java 7

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7"
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.6"
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro.I will convert the lambdas to interface for now.

Answer (score 0):

It's bit late, but I found this bug when using Map.forEach standard method, and it accepts BiConsumer (in my case I didn't use it explicitly as I'm also developing in Kotlin, so I just  passed lambda with two parameters)

And indeed it works ok with gradle plugin 3.0.0 - so it looks like some regression - for some reason it's missing from newer releases

Answer (score -2):

1) **Clean** Your Project

2) **Restart** Your Android Studio with **Invalidate cache and restart**

3) **Rebuild** Your Project

Comment: I tried this solution least 10 time.It's not working in this problem.

Comment: @KemalTürk You didn't mention that you've tried this solution. So mention it in your question rather then downvoting answer

Comment: @KemalTürk  I don't want to delete . you can leave it as it is.